# Bloodborne & Bloodborne GOTY?

Tags: bloodborne

I had the regular version of the game. -CUSA00207-
But I think to get the GOTY edition for DLC. -CUSA03173-

Both are for the same region.

The only thing I'm worried about is if the GOTY version will be able to load old save file ?

Comment: You might check if the GOTY edition simply includes a PSN key for the DLC, which would definitely mean they're compatible. The DLC and GOTY edition were released almost simultaneously, so there might not have been enough time to create a special version of the game with the new content preloaded onto the disc.

Answer (score 2):

I have never personally had an issue with this in any other games (by that, I mean I cannot speak for Bloodborne directly).
A save file for "Game X" typically works with "Game X - Y Edition"

The only thing you should be worried about is going backwards in either edition, or update version of the game (which I don't think you would be anyway, and edition isn't *typically* an issue in most games anyway)

You *could* (emphasis "could" not "will" or even "might") run into an issue if you had a save on the GOTY version and tried to play it on the standard edition for some reason. I don't have experience doing this, so maybe someone can comment and give some feedback, this is more of just an assumption.

You *likely* would run into an issue if your file was from an updated version of Bloodborne (standard edition) and you tried to play the GOTY copy before fully updating the game. (Again, I'm only assuming that the developers version Bloodborne and the GOTY edition the same. Ex: v2.0 of GOTY is the exact same as v2.0 of standard).

TL;DR: **However**, as long as you get the GOTY edition and have it updated to whatever the current version is (or at least to what version your save file was saved from) you should not run into any issues. You're definitely not the only person to buy a GOTY edition for a game in order to get some DLC for a decent price. I've done that with the past Fallout games and I think I did it with Borderlands as well, importing a save from a standard version "just worked".